# Good ways of parsing in C++

Tags: c++

I'm writing a Program in C++ that is going to use the same input files as an existing Prolog program already uses.

The files will look like these :

```
expr1(t,[f,g]).
expr1(q,[]). 
expr1(r,[e]).

expr2(a).
expr2(b).
expr2(e).

expr2(a,r).
expr2(b,d).
expr2(e,z).
```

What are some ways of parsing such files?  I've read about the [Boost Spirit](http://boost-spirit.com/home/).. anyone got thoughts on this?  Or is a way of doing it using the standard C/C++ libraries?  Ideas would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: Define "pure C++"!  Boost libraries are written in C++; they just do all the hard work for you.  If you want to write your own parser from scratch, then go for it!

Comment: I'll edit my post :).  My program will eventually be running on a cluster that doesn't have Boost so I would have to request for it to be installed.  So the standard C//C++ libraries would be preferable IF there is a nice way of doing it.

Comment: The actual libraries defined by the c++ standard are fairly thin http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Standard_Library If your cluster has any external libraries, it seems like adding in boost would be a nice addition

Comment: There is a learning curve with Boost Spirit, but then again, the knowledge can be applied elsewhere too.

Comment: This question is as subjective as it gets. Personally, I wouldn't consider using anything _other_ than Boost.Spirit...

Comment: @vivid-colours : Boost.Spirit is header-only, so where the program will be running isn't irrelevant -- only where it is built matters. (Reposting comment due to uneditable typo in my previous one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is wrong with [Flex](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/) and [Bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/)? This does have the benefit of the generated code being independent of libraries which you may or may not have. It is used for things as simple as parsing config files to things like a Javascript parser for Webkit.You might even find a Prolog grammar that you can use.

Comment: Marked as solution.. I've only used Flex/Bison for the beginnings of a compiler and didn't think of using them for this problem - obvious really!  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

That looks like a perfect job for a hand written recursive descent parser. No extra dependencies, easy to write, and straight forward for future maintainers.

Comment: If you have *The C++ Programming Language* handy, Stroustrup shows how to write a recursive descent parser in Chapter 6.  It's for a calculator, but all the steps are there.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely not suggest Boost Spirit unless the task is really a lot more complicated than what it looks lke. There is nothing wrong with Boost Spirit, I mean it is really powerfull and would do the work just fine, but it also requires a lot of learning and might massively increase the compilation time.

Although I agree with Jörgen that a hand written decent parser would be a good option, it doesn't look like you are going to need a context-free parser, so I think a regular expression parser might be enough. If that is the case, I suggest you to take a look at the new [regex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++ox#Regular_expressions) library introduced in the new C++0x standard.